# render same page for two URLs in Next Js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i need to render a same page which is a chat page for bot /chat and /chat/id urls in my next js website. [id].ts page is created under pages/chat directory and in my navbar i have a chat nav link and it goes to /chat and inside chat page i have a list of users which each user have different chat id and goes in different dynamic url like so /chat/someId
but i need to show the same [id].ts page for each of them without a page reload (like twitter web chat page) and also i need to access the id in the url via react router. the way i implement is not correct and it expect to find a different file for /chat page under pages directory. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Put the chat in a component and render it on both pages. :)

Comment: so Clean! @Sebi